# Variable gets updated out of a class but it should not python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm finally a member of the stackoverflow community, so this is my first post. I'm trying my best to create a good question.

I have a problem with a simple variable declaration in a for-loop. The variable gets declared in an if-statement and is the variable of a class. Basically what the code does is to create a box with points in it, initialise the positions and velocities of the points, edit the velocities and calculate the new positions according to their new velocities. I now want to save the initial positions of the points (means time = 0) outside of the class in a for-loop. I do this by if time = 0 then save position to a variable, but the variable gets updated to the new position in every loop iteration. The actual code is about hydrodynamics and particle interaction, but the basic structure of the code is something like this:

```
import numpy as np

class box():

    def __init__(self, boxsize, num_points, timestep):
        """
        boxsize is the size of the quadratic box in x and y direction
        num_points is the number of points in the box
        timestep is the time after that the positions should be updated
        """
        self.boxsize = float(boxsize)
        self.num_points = int(num_points)
        self.timestep = float(timestep)

        self.positions = np.zeros((self.num_points, 2)).astype(float)
        self.velocities = np.zeros((self.num_points, 2)).astype(float)

    def initialise(self):
        """initialise the positions and velocites of the points in the box, both with x- and y-components"""
        self.positions[:, :] = np.random.uniform(0., self.boxsize, size=(self.num_points, 2))
        self.velocities[:, :] = np.random.uniform(0., 1., size=(self.num_points, 2))

    def update_positions(self):
        """update position according to velocities, x- and y-components"""
        self.positions += self.velocities*self.timestep

    def new_velocities(self):
        """ create new velocities, x- and y-components """
        self.velocities[:, :] = np.random.uniform(0., 1., size=(self.num_points, 2))

    def connect_steps(self):
        """update the positions according to their velocities and create new velocities"""
        self.update_positions()
        self.new_velocities()

system = box(10., 1, 0.1) #box is 10 in x and y; 1 point in the box
system.initialise() #initialise the positions and velocities of the box

for i in range(10): #10 timesteps
    system.connect_steps()
    if i == 0.:
        r0 = system.positions
    print(r0) #here r0 should always be the same array from i = 0 but isn't
    print(r0 == system.positions) #yields True every iteration, so r0 is always the new position
```

What I want is that r0 is always the position at i = 0 (initial position), but every iteration the variable r0 gets updated according to its new position, although the if-clause and so the variable definition only gets entered once at i = 0.
It is intended to first update the positions and after that generate new velocities although they are first used in the next iteration because the real algorithm behind this velocity-generation needs the structure this way.

Maybe there is just a characteristic or property of classes I don't know.
I hope the question makes sense and anybody can help me out.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Carcigenicate usually just `my_array.copy()`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I didn't see your comment until I posted. You're welcome to answer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate in `numpy` for historical reasons, there are a lot of `array.method()` that exist alternatively as `numpy.method`

Comment: @thowal When I read your problem statement I can't help wondering if the initial position wouldn't be right after the call to `initialise` instead of after the first call to `connect_steps`.  Obviously you know your model, but I just mention it in case it was an oversight.

Comment: @user650881 thanks for the hint, the actual algorithm is a bit different, but in case of this example you would be right I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try `np.copy(system.positions)` to get a copy that won't continue to mutate as you update.

Reference https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html